# What does it mean to change the program's state in imperative programming?

Tags: state, imperative-programming

What does the following definition of imperative programming mean?

> Imperative programming is a programming paradigm that uses statements that *change a program's state*.

What is a program state, and how do you change it?

Comment: I suppose that you reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science). Look at line above: > Similarly, a computer program stores data in variables, which represent storage locations in the computer's memory. The contents of these memory locations, at any given point in the program's execution, is called the program's state.[4][5][6]

Comment: Thanks for help, that's just what I needed!